# asp.net mvc 3 strongly typed ViewData-Model compilation error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a site originally build with MVC1 later migrated to MVC2 and now I am trying to migrate it to MVC3 but I am having some trouble compiling my strongly typed ViewData.Model

The Page directive is correctly set but the compiler does not seem to pick up the correct class and complains the ViewData.Model is of type object.

Anybody had any luck solving this problem?

Intellisense seem to pick up the type correctly but not the compiler

Answer (score 3):

Check the assembly names and versions in your Web.configs.

You probably have a reference to an System.Web.Mvc.dll v2.

Comment: I am referencing the new mvc 3 library and all web.config version references have been changed from 2 to 3.

Comment: Check the base types in Views/Web.config

Comment: I had no web.config in the views folder. I added the web.config from a newly created asp.net mvc3 site so both web.config should be ok now but still no luck. Thinking about starting from scratch with razor views...

Comment: Updating the web.config in the Views folder did the trick for me.